# How do I set up a logging server for Access Points?

Tags: 12.04, logging, wireless-access-point

I have a linksys AP, nothing fancy, but it does have a logging utility. 
How do I make that send the logs my Ubuntu 12.04 server.

[image]

Comment: Does the router have the ability to log remotely? If so find out what it is using for that.

Comment: I added a picture of the router, thats all i know about the logging. @stone that's kind of my question. If i Google "logging" its trys to give results for log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is enable log reception via UDP.

In a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) run `sudo gedit /etc/rsyslog.conf`, find the following lines:

```
# provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514
```

and uncomment (remove the leading `#`) the last 2 lines, so they look like this:

```
# provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

Save, close the file then restart rsyslog by running `sudo service rsyslog restart`.

Now you can enable syslog at the AP and point it to your computer IP address. The received log entries should go to /var/log/syslog.

Comment: Can you tell me how to put those logs into a custom file?